# Customizing cross references with cleveref

Tags: hyperref, memoir, cleveref

I'm lost in the maze of customization options in the `cleveref` package. The MWE says what I'm trying to do, and my best attempt so far.

I'm running TeXLive 2013, compiling with `latexmk -pdf MWE.tex`

Note: I don't *need* a more sophisticated package than `memoir`'s extensions to `enumerate`, unless that helps solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\label{chap:one}
\section{uno}
\label{sec:uno}
\subsection{ein}
\label{subsec:ein}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
aaa
\item
\label[subsection]{enum:bbb}
bbb
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{zwei}

What I want is a cross reference that looks like ``section 1.1.1(b)''

But \verb|\cref{enum:bbb}| gives ``\cref{enum:bbb}''

\end{document}
```

Note: the comments and answer that suggest changing `enumerate` to `subsubsection` don't address the fact that I want the cross reference formatted differently from the section number in the document - as shown in the MWE, the numbering within the document should be just "(b)" but the reference should be "1.1.1(b)".

Comment: why don't you use `\subsubsection{aaa}` instead of `enumerate` environment.

Comment: @ddas In general there might be several `enumerate` environments within one `subsection`. There are very few cross-references to enumerated items, so I'm not bothered (so far!) about the possibility of ambiguous cross references. If I used `\subsubsection` I would still want the *subsubsection* numbered "(b)", and the *reference* to be "1.1.1(b)".

Comment: If you use `\subsubsection` then you would get the reference as "section 1.1.1.2". As there are very few cross-reference, is there a big deference between "1.1.1(b)" and "section 1.1.1.2".  Oh yes! I think @Robert has solved your problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps using the `enumitem` package with `shortlabels` and the `ref=....` option key is a by-pass solution.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\label{chap:one}
\section{uno}
\label{sec:uno}
\subsection{ein}
\label{subsec:ein}

\begin{enumerate}[(a),ref={\thesubsection(\alph*)}]
\item
  aaa \label{foo}
\item 
  \label[subsection]{enum:bbb}
  bbb
\end{enumerate}


\subsection{zwei}

What I want is a cross reference that looks like ``section 1.1.1(b)''

But \verb|\cref{enum:bbb}| gives ``\cref{enum:bbb}''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that this will provide a wrong reference type for the regular `foo` etc. label then!

Comment: Can you add an example showing what you mean by "this will provide a wrong reference type for the regular foo etc. label"?

Comment: @alephzero: Give `\cref{foo}` a try ;-)

Comment: "Give `\cref{foo} a try`" - I can probably live with that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I think `\cref{foo}` works just fine no?

Comment: The default horizontal spacing for the `enumerate` environment using `enumitem` is different from the `memoir` defaults - for example the indentation is bigger - but there are plenty of options in the `enumitem` package to tweak those details.

Answer (score 1):

Using in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
```

with

```
\subsubsection{aaa}
%       \item
        aaa
\subsubsection{bbb}
        \label[subsection]{enum:bbb}
        bbb
%   \end{enumerate}
```

you get more or less what you want.

[image]